# Pandas data frame column : Error while replacing string value with number

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe column which has integers and `'NA'` values. Followinareis the unique values of the column

```
 print(testData.LotFrontage.unique())  

 ['80' '81' '74' '78' '43' '75' 'NA' '63' '85' '70' '26' '21' '24']
```

I need to replace this string NA with integer 0. I tried following code

```
NAReplace = {'NA': 0}

trainingData.LotFrontage = [NAReplace[item] for item in trainingData.LotFrontage ]
```

and I am getting an error

```
    trainingData.LotFrontage = [NAReplace[item] for item in trainingData.LotFrontage ]
KeyError: '65'
```

What is the reason for this issue? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, in the list comprehension, your getting the value i the dictionary for all value,

80
81
..

The dictionary will be trying to find those keys that are also not `'NA'`, so you have to do `get`:

```
trainingData.LotFrontage = [NAReplace.get(item,item) for item in trainingData.LotFrontage ]
```

Also, pandasicer will be:

```
testData['LotFrontage'] = pd.to_numeric(testData['LotFrontage'],errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

And another one from jpp's answer.

But to add something to jpp's first one:

```
testData['LotFrontage'].replace('NA', 0,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `NAReplace` is defined as a dictionary, and the syntax `NAReplace[item]` requires `item` is a key of `NAReplace`, otherwise you see a `KeyError`.

A list comprehension isn't appropriate here in any case. Just use `fillna`:

```
testData['LotFrontage'] = testData['LotFrontage'].replace('NA', 0)
```

Most likely you want numeric data, in which case I suggest you convert to numeric:

```
testData['LotFrontage'] = pd.to_numeric(testData['LotFrontage'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

The argument `errors='coerce'` forces non-convertible values to give `NaN`.

Comment: Well, both at the same time on `pd.to_numeric` one.